# How to get parent component's name in React?

Tags: error-handling, reactjs

I would like to provide nice error messages for some of my components, like React does, for example:

> WARNING: Each child in an array should have a unique “key” prop. **Check the render method of MyComponent.** See [fb.me/react-warning-keys](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children) for more information.

This message provides some info about the context of the error. I know I can find it in the debugger, but I want to make debugging easier for me and my fellow programmers.

Comment: Is there a reason why you'd need this? React components act upon the properties they receive and their internal state, and not upon the hierarchy they belong to. Not sure if printing the parent component would help in debugging,

Comment: I created a component for handling Promises. I like it, but I ended up using it pretty much everywhere, so I'd like to improve its error handling.

Comment: I assume that the promise handlers are sent by the parent component, if that's the case then as most of the problems originate in the handlers, and those are at the parent level, you know where you are.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not clear how you'd use this with a `Promise` component you mentioned in a comment, you could try this:

```
var componentName = this.constructor.displayName || this.constructor.name || undefined;
```

It's inspired by [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b3c75d82b2c8862a461b34167bbef37a3eaa5c46/src/classic/element/ReactElementValidator.js#L59) function in the ReactJS code that looks at the constructor to build a name during React element validation.

But, if you want a parent's name, that isn't possible through any documented means and would likely be fragile if you built code depending on a specific internal implementation. It's a one way flow of information so the child doesn't need a link to its parent by way of normal architecture.

If you need the parent name, you'd need to get the value and pass it through children which I'm sure isn't desireable.

Comment: `this.constructor.displayName` prints this component name (which is nice, but not what I wanted, as I wanted the parent one), and `constructor.name` is always `Window` for me (most likely you meant `this.constructor.name` there).

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't understand what you wanted the parent's value like that as it wasn't described in your question (the example was showing what I provided). I've updated my answer to say it's not possible using any supported means.

Comment: How about the functional component?